# C# - Can't override ==

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, operator-overloading, overriding, iequatable

I have the following class (built for Unity Game Engine)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Biome : ScriptableObject, IEquatable<Biome>
{
    // ...

    //
    // IEquatable
    //

    public bool Equals(Biome other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return this.name == other.name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        Biome other = obj as Biome;

        if (other == null) return false;

        return Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Biome biome1, Biome biome2)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(biome1, biome2)) return true;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, biome1)) return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, biome2)) return false;

        return biome1.Equals(biome2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Biome biome1, Biome biome2)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(biome1, biome2)) return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(biome1, null)) return true;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(biome2, null)) return true;

        return !biome1.Equals(biome2);
    }
}
```

When I try to do test, the function `Equals` seems to be working, but the operator `==` gives me a different result.

```
    [Test]
    public void FooTest()
    {
        ScriptableObject biome1 = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance("Biome");
        ScriptableObject biome2 = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance("Biome");

        biome1.name = "Biome #1";
        biome2.name = "Biome #1";

        Assert.IsTrue(biome1.Equals(biome2));
        Assert.IsTrue(biome1 == biome2);  // This one fails

    }
```

Am I doing something wrong with my implementation?

**UPDATE:** Here is the full class, in case it makes a difference: https://www.hastebin.com/divazubero.cpp

Comment: FYI the typical implementation for `!=` is just `return !(a == b)`

Comment: Did you debug? Note that `if (other == null)` calls your `==` operator again.

Comment: So how does the compiler determine which Equals method to use when you pass a biome that is both a Biome() and an object? Sorry if this is off topic, but I've never encountered this sort of thing.

Comment: So, I took the time to copy your code and test it....it works for me...both calls return `true`. So it seems there is more code or information that is relevant to this problem.

Comment: I added a link with the full class.

Comment: Why does your C# file have a cpp extension?

Comment: I apologize, I made a little mistake when copying... my test variables were both of type `Biome`. If they're `object` I get your result. Seems @emsimpson92 has a point.

Comment: @juharr it is just hastebin.com, that tries to guess the language. It just guessed it wrong. Mine is a .cs file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your variables are of type `ScriptableObject`, not of type `Biome`.

The compiler has to decide at *compile-time* which overload to call. And since it does not know at compile-time that the run-time type will be `Biome`, it emmits a call to the `==` operator of `ScriptableObject`.
If that class doesn't have a overridden `==` operator, the operator of `object` is called (which does a simple `ReferenceEquals` which is of course `false`).

`==` operator overloading is **not** `virtual`.

If you use the *specific*  type `Biome` in your test, it will work as expected.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Even though when I try to cast, it gives me a compilation error, and I am not sure why. But that is indeed the reason why the assetion fails.